# onRecieve() method of Broadcastreceiver is not called when I run the app Log.d() not show on log cat

Tags: android

`onReciever()` method of Broadcastreceiver is not called when I run the app Log.d() not show on log cat
-manifest file is following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Audio.audioplayer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver 
            android:name=".MyReceiver">
         <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />

       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Audio.audioplayer.PlayerAudioActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.Audio.audioplayer.PlayerAudioActivity" />

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my broadcastreceiver class is following:

```
package com.Audio.audioplayer;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver 
extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive
       (Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
        {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB","OOOOOOOOOOO");
        }
        else
        {
             Toast.makeText(context, "Intent not Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("shit","O");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you want to fire bootreciever

Comment: i not understand what you saying me bootreciever i have no idea

Comment: bootreciever works when system changes occurs like this work when you network is connected and disconnected in device

Comment: try to switch off wifi from settings in your device then see logcat

Comment: I switched off but no effect on output

Comment: it's `onReceive`, not `onReciever`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootreciever works when system changes occurs like this work when you network is connected and disconnected in device

try this

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">

 <intent-filter>        
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/><action   
android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/><action  
android:name="android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: i am using a mobile as emulator and as you telling me i switched off the wifi but no result of log.d in logCat file